# Write data in a binary field in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I have already convert the "Password" input with this code

```
Dim password As String = (MyPass + MyUName)
    Dim mhash As HashAlgorithm = New SHA1CryptoServiceProvider
    Dim bytValue() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password)
    Dim bytHash() As Byte = mhash.ComputeHash(bytValue)
    mhash.Clear()
    ENPass = Convert.ToBase64String(bytHash)
```

And with this code I'm taking back a byte array same like the bytHash

```
Dim Text As String = Convert.ToString(OfficeCommsRecs(5))
    Dim oReturn As New StringBuilder
    Dim Separator As String = ("")
    For Each Character As Byte In ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Text)
        oReturn.Append(Convert.ToString(Character, 2).PadLeft(8, "1"))
        oReturn.Append(Separator)
    Next
    Dim myPass As Object = oReturn
```

What I have to do to take back the password?

Comment: can you post your VB code that does that? I suspect you are trying to save a `string` representation of the binary data when you really should be using `byte[]` instead

Comment: wOlf yes tha is what i do and i see that is not the wright one. please can you give a guide line what to do about?

Comment: Sorry I just see that it works the same without turn it to string

Comment: My method might not be what you are looking for, but I usually create a new field with the desired data type (here binary) and use an `UPDATE` to insert the values in the new binary field, after which I delete the no-more-needed varchar field. I do this when I cannot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Text)` gives you back a byte array. Use that directly in your data access code, as the value of an `SqlParameter`.

You don't need the rest of the code that you posted in the question: it only creates a human-readable representation of the byte array, but the database does not understand that. It expects a `Byte()`, not a `String`.

#### Update

I just realized I was a fool - I kept thinking about the technical problem (save/load binary data) and missed the big picture: **you are not supposed to read the password back**. So, hashing is the right way to go, but please check out this great article while you're at it: http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Comment: OK right now I'm in position to have (back) the bytes like the bytHas in my encoding code above. What I have to do next to take back the password?

Comment: @LefterisGkinis jsut retrieve the data normally from the DB (using `DataAdapter` or `DataReader`). Your `Password` column will now contain a `byte()` value. Transfer that `byte()` back to `string`, using [`ASCII.GetString(passwordBytes)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc.aspx)

Comment: @wOlf I did that and i didn't get what i want. that GetString returns me the record itself which is finally converted to Convert.ToBase64String

Comment: I have put the code which helps me to convert the password end put it to the SQL record. Now I'm taking this encoded record and I need to Decode in order to take back the password.

Comment: If you're converting to base 64, why does it need to be stored in the database as binary?

Comment: Yes dear ErikE I change my idea of handling the password, and in fact that will be more safe. Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the store procedure then pass the string and use the convert function of sql before store the data like Convert(binary,).

Answer (score 0):

Find the below example for insert string in binary format:

---Create Table

Create Table Test
(
Password binary(1000)
)

---Create Proc for insert value

Create Proc InsertValue 
@password nvarchar(200)
as
Insert into Test(Password)
Values (Convert(binary,@password))

--Insert value

Exec InsertValue 'NewPasword'

-----Fetch the binary data and converted data

Select Password , Convert(nvarchar(200), Password) Password From Test

Comment: I user this for writing images I believe it's the same.